# Record requires ASM8

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, build

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDevDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform moshi-1.14.0.jar (com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.14.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=devDebug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=29, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.environment=standard-jvm, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
      > Execution failed for AsmClassesTransform: /Users/kenhung/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a16d64e72d31d3256425679f6c024bf4/jetified-moshi-1.14.0.jar.
         > Record requires ASM8
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
I have tried to add android.jetifier.ignorelist , android.jetifier.blacklist